# Plot a vegetation transect with dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with (a lot of) transect with terrein height (x is horizontal distance and z is elevation, both in meters) and vegetation structure. b_ml, b_kl1, b_kl2 and b_s1 are coverage of the moss layer, herb layer 1, herb layer 2 and shrub layer in % and h_?? is height of the same layers (moss layer always 3 cm). I want to present these data in attractive graphs. Here's a sample of the data (1 transect):

```
#sample data
structure(list(X = c(432529.4846, 432530.4562, 432531.3492, 432532.3046, 
432533.3252, 432533.3419, 432534.3361, 432535.2709, 432536.3843, 
432537.4198, 432538.4336, 432539.3736, 432540.448, 432541.3967, 
432542.2748, 432543.0681, 432544.2508, 432545.2269, 432546.0911, 
432547.0195, 432548.0396, 432549.0209, 432549.9539, 432550.9391, 
432551.8999, 432552.8647, 432553.8258, 432554.7889, 432555.7722, 
432556.7435, 432557.7456, 432558.714, 432559.6824, 432560.6456, 
432561.6306, 432562.6059, 432563.5442, 432564.5688, 432565.5408, 
432566.5742), Z = c(10.6399, 10.5674, 10.4631, 10.3553, 10.2856, 
10.2392, 10.1234, 10.0792, 10.037, 9.9068, 9.834, 9.7207, 9.6024, 
9.5322, 9.3343, 9.2266, 9.0705, 8.9673, 8.9716, 8.8292, 8.7495, 
8.6541, 8.5429, 8.4306, 8.2933, 8.1877, 7.9679, 7.7799, 7.6801, 
7.5073, 7.3754, 7.2414, 7.0254, 7.0095, 6.8553, 6.7976, 6.7528, 
6.7151, 6.5225, 6.1952), b_ml = c(0.1, 0.05, NA, 0.1, 0.05, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.05, NA, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.01, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), h_kl1 = c(75, 75, 70, 80, 80, 70, NA, 30, 
30, 50, 60, 60, 60, 60, 40, 30, 30, 70, 10, 10, 10, 20, 30, 30, 
30, 15, 15, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3), b_kl1 = c(0.9, 
0.95, 0.85, 0.95, 0.95, 0.9, NA, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.4, 
0.05, 0.6, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.98, 1, 1, 0.98, 
0.98, 0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 0.9, 0.8, 0.4, 0.95, 0.98, 0.95, 0.5, 
0.25, 0.05, 0.01), h_kl2 = c(110, 110, 110, 100, NA, 110, NA, 
110, 110, 100, 110, 120, 110, 110, 110, 70, 70, 120, 130, 120, 
110, 50, 80, NA, 90, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
45, 45, 25, NA, NA), b_kl2 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, NA, 0.1, 
NA, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95, 
0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.01, NA, 0.01, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, NA, NA), h_s1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 300, 250, NA, NA, NA, 270, 270, 250, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), b_s1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.7, 0.6, NA, NA, NA, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("X", "Z", "b_ml", "h_kl1", 
"b_kl1", "h_kl2", "b_kl2", "h_s1", "b_s1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 40:79)
```

I have tried plotting them with geom_line and geom_pointrange, using density as alpha, but that doesn't look nice:

```
#set the terrein heigth
ld <- 2
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X,y=Z)) + geom_line()

#add the vegetation layers
p + geom_line(aes(x=X,y=Z+0.02, alpha = b_ml), size = ld, color = "darkgreen") + 
    geom_line(aes(x=X,y=Z+h_kl1/100, alpha = b_kl1), size = ld, color = "green") +  #divide by 100 because z is in meters and h in cm
    geom_line(aes(x=X,y=Z+h_kl2/100, alpha = b_kl2), size = ld, color = "green") +
    geom_line(aes(x=X,y=Z+h_s1/100, alpha = b_s1), size = ld, color = "brown") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
#add the vegetation layers with pointrange
p + geom_pointrange(aes(x = X, ymin = Z, ymax=Z+0.03, alpha = b_ml), color = "darkgreen") + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = X, ymin = Z+0.03, ymax=Z+h_kl1/100, alpha = b_kl1), color = "green") + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = X, ymin = Z+h_kl1/100, ymax=Z+h_kl2/100, alpha = b_kl2), color = "green") +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = X, ymin = Z+h_kl2/100, ymax=Z+h_s1/100, alpha = b_s1), color = "brown") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I think I would like to make a better looking plot with a density of dots representing the density of the layer. Like in this picture from Nature:
[image]

Essentially, the area between two layers is filled with dots, the number of dots depends on the density/coverage.
But I'm a bit stuck on how to get there. I've also thought about 'geom_point' and 'geom_dotplot', but that would include calculating points by hand.

Any suggestions on how to achieve that? Eg. which geom to use (jitter?), or how to restructure my data?

Comment: For your first plot, I'm getting `object 'ld' not found`

Comment: Sorry corrected @jakub

Comment: I am going to assume that your question is not "I want it to look nice" but "How do I get to that Nature plot". In which case, my guess would be `geom_point` (but it would also need many more data points in order to look like the Nature one). Does that get you any closer to what you want?

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what your variables are, and why you are doing calculations such as `Z+h_kl1/100`, or why you are mapping `b_kl1` to alpha.

Comment: @Axeman You're right, it is a bit vague. I've added more info.

Comment: So `Z` is elevation, and the vegetation heights are in cm?

Comment: @jakub I would like that nature-plot style, but projected on the elevation slope. But I am open to other suggestions of presenting it. And geom_point won't work, because it gives me only one point at the height. In the nature plot, the area between two layers is filled with dots, depenping on the density.

Comment: @Axeman yes. Elevation is a better English word for terrein height.

Comment: @RHA I am a bit confused. If I want to have a dot in my plot, I need to know its coordinates. This means, I need to have data. So I need as many data points as there are dots in the plot. If this data does not exist (because you only have a single data point per height), than you have to create it and then use `jitter` for example (which randomizes their position) and `geom_point`. You have to use density to determine the amount of "artificial data" you need. This would create cloud of dots around your original dot (you can shift it in space of course...).

Comment: But looking at that Nature plot, I don't think the dots are merely meaning density - they also form patterns, don't they?

Comment: This will perhaps be difficult to explain to non-vegetation ecologists. In the field it is impossible to measure the height of every individual plant or branch. Therefore, one estimates the density and mean maximum height per layer. Representing this by random dots is not confusing but actually comes quite close to reality.
The nature plot is indeed probably made with some sort of scanning technique, my data is different. I just included it as an example of what i am after.

Comment: If you can concede that this is confusing for non-vegetation ecologists, imagine how confused neuroscientists are :)) I think I finally get what you need, but I'm on the same boat with @Axeman regarding data simulation for this purpose. If the Nature plot is a result of a specific technique, I would consider it an extra reason against - since then you are puting a false idea into observer's mind (i.e., that the dots correspond to actual data points, which they don't). I know this is not my field. Just think carefully before making your coding efforts (so they're not wasted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have the actual data to create a plot as your example, simply because they seem to have an actual ton of datapoints (individuals observations? some kind of scanning technique?) while you only have density estimates. Creating points out of that seems confusing at best, and potentially misleading. If you have the raw data from which these densities were computed, then maybe this was a different story. Below are some examples of plots that you *can* make:

First I rearrange the data in tidy format so things make a bit more sense:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

densities <- df %>% 
  select(-h_kl1, -h_kl2, -h_s1) %>% 
  gather('type', 'density', b_ml, b_kl1, b_kl2, b_s1) %>% 
  mutate(type = substring(type, 3))
heights <- df %>% 
  select(-b_ml, -b_kl1, -b_kl2, -b_s1) %>% 
  gather('type', 'height', h_kl1, h_kl2, h_s1) %>% 
  mutate(type = substring(type, 3))
df2 <- left_join(densities, heights) %>% 
  mutate(height = ifelse(type == 'ml', 0.03, height / 100),
         type = factor(type, levels = c('s1', 'kl2', 'kl1', 'ml')))
```

Attempt 1:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(X, Z)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Z, ymax = Z + height, alpha = density, col = type), size = 4) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 0.7))
```

[image]

A problem is that `ml` is nearly invisible because it has such a different scale from the others. We could try dodging:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(X, Z)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Z, ymax = Z + height, alpha = density, col = type), 
                 size = 2, position = position_dodge(1))
```

[image]

That doesn't help much. Perhaps facetting:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(X, Z)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Z, ymax = Z + height, alpha = density, col = type), size = 4) +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

[image]

One last option:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(X, Z)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(y = Z + height, size = density, col = type), alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

I think this one quite clearly shows the trends in vegetation. I like that is gives equal emphasis to the different categories.

Including segments:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(X, Z)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = X, yend = Z + height), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Z + height, size = density, col = type), alpha = 0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but it's not what i am after. The facets don't appeal to me, because the layers form a structure together and the total number of plots would be 4 times as high. Stacking them would be a better option, but still not ideal. I think geom_point with jitter is the way to go, replicating the points according to density. I'll try that after lunch.

Comment: Stacking would misrepresent their heights. And I respectfully disagree about conjuring up data being a good thing.

Comment: Yes, one would have to subtract the previous layers first.

Comment: @RHA One additional option added.

Comment: I had't considered that, not bad at all (+1 for the idea). I will continue to look for other option, but this is the best so far.

Comment: Update: after much thinking/trying and testing the plots on co-workers, I've decided that your last option (geom_segment +geom_point) is the best representation of my data (so answer accepted). Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with you submission (I assume).

Answer (score 1):

I've come quite closer to a solution myself using geom_jitter. To show what I would like to do (and to counter the totally unfounded accusations of 'conjuring up data' and 'puting a false idea into observer's mind'[sic]) I'll post my attempt here:

```
#make a tidy data.frame (taken from @Axeman)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

densities <- df %>% 
  select(-h_kl1, -h_kl2, -h_s1) %>% 
  gather('type', 'density', b_ml, b_kl1, b_kl2, b_s1) %>% 
  mutate(type = substring(type, 3))
heights <- df %>% 
  select(-b_ml, -b_kl1, -b_kl2, -b_s1) %>% 
  gather('type', 'height', h_kl1, h_kl2, h_s1) %>% 
  mutate(type = substring(type, 3))
df2 <- left_join(densities, heights) %>% 
  mutate(height = ifelse(type == 'ml', 0.03, height / 100),
         type = factor(type, levels = c('s1', 'kl2', 'kl1', 'ml')))

# repeat rows according to density
# multiply density by 100: 1% will be 10 dots, 100%, 1000 dots and NA -> 1 (jitter can't handle NA)
df2$repli <- df2$density*1000
df2$repli[is.na(df2$repli)] <- 1

df3 <- df2[rep(rownames(df2), df2$repli), ]

require(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df3, aes(x=X,y=Z)) + geom_line(size = 1.5, colour = "gray") + theme_bw()

p + #geom_line(aes(y = Z + height, col = type)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(y = Z + height/2, col = type), position = position_jitter(width = 1, height = df3$height), 
                size = 0.0001, alpha = 0.1 ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("brown", "#CCFF00", "#33CC00","#666600"))
```

[image]

It's still not perfect, because there are some warning messages I don't understand, there is overlap between the 'jitters' and some smaller issues. But it comes close to what I originally had in mind: a visual representation of the vegetation layers, getting the height and density across.

And looking aesthetically, Axemans 'last option' is more appealing I think.